# NoMethodError Undefined Method `formats` for `modify`:String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, format, ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror

I have a method named "modify" inside my PurchaseOrdersController, it also has its template (modify.slim) inside the view directory.

Let say, I'm on this path `http://localhost:3000/purchase_orders/modify?prid=1`

The problem is when I'm going to click the anchor tag ('/po/1.pdf') which opens newtab, the:

`NoMethodError (undefined method formats for "modify":String
Did you mean?  form_tag):`

occurs when I hit refresh the page `http://localhost:3000/purchase_orders/modify?prid=1`.

Does anyone has the idea how to fix this? I'm using Rails 5.2.1.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** please see [Rails Logs](https://pastebin.com/PJPCrAYV), [Code: Controller, View](https://pastebin.com/VG2s0utH)

Comment: Not enough information to debug it, can you show controller and view code for corresponding action.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace for the exception? And the Rails server logs showing where the request was routed before the exception was throw.

Comment: I added Rails logs link, Sir @ScottBartell for debugging.

Comment: @Gabbar, please see my code.

Comment: @Charlie From the stacktrace, what is line 21 in `purchase_orders_controller.rb`? `app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:21`

Comment: @ScottBartell, It's `@po = @pr.purchase_orders.first`. You may see it on the link I just added recently, the `def modify` part.

Comment: Not sure but can you please check replacing the last line in the method with `respond_to do |format| 
      format.html 
    end`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, Thanks but the error still there.

Comment: Are you including any modules inside of a class? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23472072/1298944

Comment: @ScottBartell, Yes! `class PurchaseOrderReportPdf < Prawn::Document...end` before that line there is `include ActionView::Helpers`. I removed it and now the error is Gone! Thank you so much!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Rails to properly load files, make sure any modules you have included are done so inside the respective class. For example:

```rb
class MyClass
  include ActionView::Helpers
end
```

See [this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23472072/1298944).